# Why does uname -r differ from manjaro-settings-manager?

Tags: linux, kernel, manjaro

I'm trying to install some drivers for my kernel. Thus I need to find out my kernel version.

While `uname -r` returns `4.9.43-1-MANJARO`, the `manjaro-settings-manager` shows `Linux 4.9.44-1` as `running` and `installed`.

Why is that? How can this difference be explained and what is the actual version, I am running?

Also, how could I install header files for version 43-1 ? pacman only finds headers for 44-1.

Comment: Did you reboot since you last updated your kernel version?

Comment: @MariusMatutiae I think so but I don't know. After a reboot (with advanced settings and choosing 44-1 it went smooth)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that in this case `manjaro-settings-manager` is incorrect in stating that `Linux 4.9.44-1` is running on your system. This is probably an issue with how that settings manager detects the running kernel.

`uname` gets its information reliably from [a system call](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/136959). You can check yourself by running `cat /proc/sys/kernel/osrelease`.

I  expect that what has happened is your system installed `4.9.44-1`, but you are still running `4.9.43-1` because you haven't rebooted yet.

Finally, pacman only finds headers for 44-1 because that is the nature of the rolling release distro - pacman only lists and installs the latest version it finds.

If you wanted to downgrade manually you could run `pacman -U /var/cache/pacman/pkg/<package file>`, but you'd also have to downgrade its dependencies for consistency.